# ELIF statement is causing my insert statement to be skipped

Tags: python

I have found a bug in my ELIF API fetch that writes into a SQL table.

Basically when the ELIF condition is false/does not exist it skips the insert into my SQL table instead of just ignoring that condition and capturing all conditions which are true into the associated variables.

a small snippet of code:

```
try:
            for period in events:
                for group in period.get('groups'):
                    for item in group.get('statisticsItems'):
                        eventid = EventId
                        if period.get('period') == 'ALL':
                            if item.get('name') == 'Ball possession':
                                hometeampossessionft = item.get('home')
                                awayteampossessionft = item.get('away')
                            elif item.get('name') == 'Total shots':
                                hometeamtotalshotsft = item.get('home')
                                awayteamtotalshotsft = item.get('away')
                            elif item.get('name') == 'Shots on target':
                                hometeamshotsontargetft = item.get('home')
                                awayteamshotsontargetft = item.get('away')
```

So what happens is if Shots on target does not exist it just skips the entire line and doesn't write it into my SQL table, AND as an even weirder one for me If I move Ball Possession to the bottom as the last elif it only writes that one into my table as it is the first entry in the dictionary and doesn't loop through the dictionary items one by one to look for the matching condition.

Any ideas would be very very welcome!

EDIT - Adding a snippet from the API call to show why the FOR loops are the way they are:

```
{
    "statistics": [
        {
            "period": "ALL",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "groupName": "Possession",
                    "statisticsItems": [
                        {
                            "name": "Ball possession",
                            "home": "45%",
                            "away": "55%",
                            "compareCode": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "groupName": "Shots",
                    "statisticsItems": [
                        {
                            "name": "Total shots",
                            "home": "11",
                            "away": "4",
                            "compareCode": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shots off target",
                            "home": "8",
                            "away": "2",
                            "compareCode": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that has anything to do with inserting into a database table. You also have multiple variables that are undefined. Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand what you are trying to do and help you from there. Be sure to include example input and output.

Comment: I don't see any code here that would write to an SQL table.  If your question is about that, you'll have to include it here.

Comment: It might help to remove the `for` loops entirely since that doesn't seem to be a concern for your question. Instead. give an example `period` and `item` that illustrates what is happening in the `if..elif` chain.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess that it's because you're referring to a variable such as `hometeampossessionft` later on in the code, but that variable was never defined because the item name was not equal to "Ball possession", and so an exception is thrown, skipping the remainder of the `try` block.

Comment: The question is directly related to the loop above, My ultimate goal is to insert it into the SQL table but the problem is not with the insert the problem is the loop above kills the line if the ELIF condition is not met instead of skipping and moving to check the next condition - I have updated the question with a snippet out of the API call to show why the loops run the way they do

Comment: @JohnGordon - yes that is exactly what is happening, I write these into variables and then use the variables to insert into the table, however, I set defaults for all of them prior to the loops running like hometeampossessionft = 0 etc

Comment: We really can't help without seeing the whole code.  The code you've shown us only sets some variables, but you're asking why some items don't get written to a database table, and you haven't shown us that code at all.